# Why is it advantageous to use to moving two particles to collide in a head-on collision, over a stationary target?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, collision, particle-accelerators

I have seen similar questions on this topic but I am more specifically wondering for particle accelerators what the effect on momentum and its relation, (if there is one) to the de Brogilei wavelength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two particles collide head-on with equal but opposite velocities, all of the  energy content of both particles is available to create new product particles in the collision. This lets physicists explore higher energy phenomena than they can when colliding one moving particle with another which is stationary in the lab reference frame. De Broglie effects don't directly enter into the picture here.

Comment: Thanks for your help!